# How to redirect to rootviewcontroller on click of Tab bar item in iOS App (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am implementing an iOS App with `UITabBar` with `UINavigationViewController` in Swift. Now facing an issue,

If I select first tab, I can see 'A' `ViewController`, and on click of any contents of 'A', I redirect to 'B' `UINavigationViewController`, Now If I click on Second tab, and then again Clicks the first tab, It is showing 'B' `NavigationViewController`. Expected is, It should display 'A' `ViewController`. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try implementing `didSelectViewController` delegate and then on selection of 'A ViewController' index redirect to root viewcontroller.

```
  func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    let index : Int = (tabBarController.viewControllers?.indexOf(viewController))!
    if index == 0
    {
        let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController
        navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

}
```

[Download Sample](http://www.filedropper.com/tabdelegate)

Comment: Can you please explain it more clearly. I am also having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBAction func itemB(sender: UIButton) {
    // do something 
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**In Swift 3.1**

Add `UITabBarControllerDelegate` to your TabBar Class:

```
class YourClass: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
```

After:

```
override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {

    let yourView = self.viewControllers![self.selectedIndex] as! UINavigationController
    yourView .popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false) 

}
```